# How to find and add the function to id?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a function to the attribute `onChange` of the element with `id="custom-taxonomy"`. I don't want to edit the file.
I want to have a javascript solution.

My idea is to find the element by the `id` and then add the function.
How can i achiev this idea?

The code:

```
<div id ="custom-taxonomy">PRODUCT PRICES</div>
```

Expected result:

```
<div id ="custom-taxonomy" name="custom-product" onchange="return chothuephuongxa();>PRODUCT PRICES</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and `document.getElementById`

```js
let elm = document.getElementById('custom-taxonomy')
elm.setAttribute('name',"custom-product")
elm.setAttribute("onclick","return chothuephuongxa();")
console.log(elm.outerHTML)
```

```html
<div id ="custom-taxonomy">PRODUCT PRICES</div>
```

**Note**:

- You can't use [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) attribute of `<div>` but using `elm.name = ...` because `name` property in not available on `<div>` elements.
- Similarly `elm.onclick = "return chothuephuongxa();"` is not correct because this will set event to `string` instead of function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to add attributes to elements:

```
document.getElementById('custom-taxonomy').setAttribute('name', 'custom-product');
```

the same can be done for your event.